# Python background threads

Tags: python, multithreading

Given this code snippet:

```
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    list = []
    counter = 0
    while True:
        counter = counter + 1
        time.sleep(0.0033)
        list.append(counter)
```

I would like to create a thread which runs in the background doing some metadata calculations (finding the sum of the elements in the array) on the array "list" being populated in real time in the while loop.

Comment: We already know what you want, what is your question and what have you tried to solve it? There are many post about threads in python, have you read any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import time
import threading


if __name__ == "__main__":

    def print_sum(l):
        while True:
            total = sum(l)
            print("the total is {}".format(total))
            time.sleep(1)


    #list = [] - should not use 'list'. - this shadows the built in object name list.
    l = []
    counter = 0
    thread = threading.Thread(target=print_sum,args=(l,))
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()
    while True:
        counter = counter + 1
        l.append(counter)
        time.sleep(1)
```

This spins up a thread in the background running function `print_sum` to display the sum of the list.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I needed!